# How to delete Tag by Name in EA

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I have created 10 Tags by using C#. Out of 10 Tag I just wants to delete 3 Tags.

How to delete Tag by Name?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way to delete information via the automation interface is by index.  To delete you will need to iterate that Collection, find which index contains the item you want to delete, then call the Delete or DeleteAt function with the appropriate index.

Answer (score -1):

Using the sql query you can try this

```
select PropertyID from t_objectproperties where Object_ID= "Pass the element id" and Property= "Tag name";
```

Once u get the property id then using that u can try deleteing